# How to bind id value but display name value using Buefy Autocomplete?

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete, vue-component, vuex, buefy

I'm trying to integrate [Buefy Autocomplete](https://buefy.github.io/documentation/autocomplete/) in my site. My data is an array of objects, each containing an integer ID and a String name. Like so

```
countries : [
    {
        id: 1
        name : 'Country 1',
    },
    {
        id: 2
        name : 'Country 2',
    },
]
```

As the documentation says the `field` property is used to display as the selected value and returns the same value

I would like to use the `name` property as the display text but the `id` as the selected option.

Also when I get the result from API I get the country `id`, and I would like to set the value based on `id`

Here is the sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ox3zmta/)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you select a suggestion from the Autocomplete dropdown it doesn't just select the `id` or the `name`, it selects the whole object `{...}`.

So once you have it selected you should be able to choose which field you want to use from there on, in your case, the `id`.

In a Codepen of one of the examples you can see that the whole object is selected - https://codepen.io/pen?&editable=true&editors=101

Are you sure you're only getting the `id` and not the whole object?